# Can't clone an object in php simple dom parser

Tags: php, parsing, clone

First things first, I'd like to make sure the below is the right way to test and clone an object.  I'm using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

```
$page = 'www.google.ca';
$html = file_get_html($page);

$test = clone $html;

$test->find('title',0)->innertext = 'changed title';

echo $html->find('title',0)->innertext;
echo $test->find('title',0)->innertext;
```

Now maybe I'm doing it wrong, but this doesn't seem to clone $html to $test.  Both will output 'changed title'.

So my question(s) is,

1. Am I cloning correctly?
2. Is there another way of cloning an object in PHP?

Thanks guys

Comment: `clone` only performs a shallow copy. It could be that the actual DOM is just a property (another object) of `$html`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documantation says so:

> When an object is cloned, PHP 5 will perform a shallow copy of all of the object's properties. Any properties that are references to other variables, will remain references.

So maybe .innertext refers to another object, and it's a reference.

Have you tried `$test = $html;`?

Comment: I did try that at first, but any changes made to one were made to another.  I did figure out (I think) how to fix it, I parse the object into a string and converted it back to an object using the class' own functions...............$test = str_get_html($html->outertext);